# Using Raspberry Pi - 2 / 3 in wireless ad hoc networks using IPv6 addresses

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pi-2, networking, wifi

How to connect multiple Raspberry Pis (Pi -2 and Pi - 3) using WLAN(wifi) in Ad Hoc fashion? Is it possible to use IPv6 addressing schemes rather than IPv4? Since IPv6 addresses are quite long, how can one use **avahi** to resolve a Pi within the network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Wireless Ad Hoc Networking with Raspberry Pi - 2 Model B / Pi - 3 with IPv6

OS used: **Raspbian Jessie 8.0**

kernel version:

- **4.4.38-v7+** for Raspberry Pi 3
- **4.4.13-v7+** for Raspberry Pi - 2

---

> Raspberry Pi - 2 Model B require *specific* external USB WLAN dongle for
>   creating Ad Hoc networks, while as the internal WLAN module for Raspberry Pi 3 is sufficient.

#### External USB Dongles

Tests with following **Drivers** on the dongles for creation of ad hoc networks were conducted:

| **Driver Name**   |     **USB dongle**     |

| **Ralink RT5370** | LogiLink WL1045A v.2.0 |

|**Ralink R8188EU** | LogiLink WL1045A v.1.0|

In order to check if any USB dongle one uses features the above mentioned drivers perform the following command:

```
lsmod | grep "cfg80211"
```

The command would specifically tell you which driver module is available for WLAN e.g. `brcmfmac` for Pi - 3, `r8188eu` or `rt2x00lib` for external dongles.

**Note**:

> **Edimax 7811UN** dongles or dongles with `8192cu` drivers are **Incompatible** in forming ad hoc networks.

---

#### Unique Local Addresses (ULA) IPv6

Synonymous to [IPv4 Private Addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) viz.

- 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255
- 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255
- 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255

[ULA for IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_local_address) can be assigned to each Pi for Unicast purpose.
They start with `fd00::/8`.

For instance, a Pi can have an ULA address: `fd23:4567:89ab:1::1/64` and another pi may have
`fd23:4567:89ab:1::2/64`.

To get more information or generate a random **ULA** for an application, refer to [Unique Local IPv6 Generator](http://unique-local-ipv6.com/)

---

### Configuration Steps

For both the Pis, we use the `iwconfig` cmdline tool to create a ad hoc network. Adding the IPv6 address can be done by using `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

**Pi - 3 Configuration**

- `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

  ```
  # only showing wlan0 Configuration
  # for brevity

  auto wlan0
  allow-hotplug wlan0
  iface wlan0 inet6 static

    address fd23:4567:89ab:1::1
    netmask 64
    autoconf 1
    dad-attempts 0
    accept ra 0
  ```
- for ad hoc Configuration:

  ```
  sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc
  sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid my-adhoc
  sudo iwconfig wlan0 channel 1
  ```

  to check if your wireless network is configured do the following:

  ```
  iwconfig wlan0
  ```

  which should produce the following output:

  ```
  wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"my-adhoc"  
  Mode:Ad-Hoc  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Cell: 72:FD:2F:DC:FD:CE
  Tx-Power=20 dBm
  Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
  Power Management:off
  ```

  parameter like `Tx-Power` and `Power Management` can be changed using `iwconfig`.

  ```
  # for Tx-Power to be 5 dBm
  iwconfig wlan0 txpower 5
  ```
- Finally, perform `sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup wlan0` to set the ULA on `wlan0`.

  ```
  ifconfig wlan0
  wlan0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:74:65:d6  
    inet6 addr: fd5d:12c9:2201:1::1/64 Scope:Global
    inet6 addr: fe80::beef:ebff:fe11:dead/64 Scope:Link
    UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
  ```

  ULA is assigned and `fe80::beef:ebff:fe11:dead` is your [Link-Local Address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) synonymous to IPv4 `169.254.0.0/16`.

**Pi - 2 Configuration**

- `/etc/network/interfaces` file is the same as previously mentioned for Pi - 3. The Pi - 2 may have the address as `fd23:4567:89ab:1::2` with other parameters being the same.
- Since the WLAN dongle is external for Pi - 2, it is preferable to do the following steps to configure ad hoc operation:

  ```
  sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
  sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc
  sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid my-adhoc
  sudo iwconfig wlan0 channel 1
  sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
  ```
- add the ULA address to `wlan0` using `sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup wlan0`
- To check perform `iwconfig wlan0` and `ifconfig wlan0` on Pi - 2

---

### Checking connectivity

instead of `ping` we use `ping6` in the following way:

- Pi - 3 --> Pi -2

  ```
  ping6 -I wlan0 fd23:4567:89ab:1::2
  ```

  This should ping your Pi - 2 proving both your pis are in Ad-Hoc operation wirelessly.

---

### Using mDNS Avahi

For IPv6 change the following files on the Pis:

- in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` change to the line with `[hosts]` to the following:

  ```
  hosts:      files mdns_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns
  ```
- in order to use the `.local` domain add `search local` in the
  `/etc/resolv.conf`.
- In `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf` make sure you have `use-ipv6=yes`.
- In the end It is suggested to reboot your Pis and configure them to the Ad Hoc
  mode using `iwconfig` again. or a bash script can be created and triggered on
  boot.

Finally you can now reach the Pis using their names:

```
ping6 -I wlan0 myPi3.local
```

or

```
ping6 -I wlan0 myPi2.local
```

This proves to be useful also when using `ssh`:

```
ssh -I wlan0 -l pi myPi3.local
```

or

```
ssh -I wlan0 -l pi myPi2.local
```

To resolve the Name and Address of a pi in the Ad Hoc network use:

```
avahi-resolve -n nameofpi.local
```

Comment: Is this some sort of tutorial that you followed for installation or you wrote this? what is the problem/question?

Comment: No I have been working with ad hoc networks for a year and I tried all possible ways to create it. I just wrote this as a part of references for future usage. The problem was with Edimax dongles and their incomptibility to form ad hoc networks. But on the contrary other dongles with their respective drivers worked so thought of sharing the answer. For generic references

Comment: @hcheung I am still open to modifications to both the answer and question. Any suggestions?

Comment: First of all, this is not a place to self-post a question and self-answering a question. If you want to share with your write-up, try post it on your own blog or github or other platform. Secondly, your 2nd post give me an impression that you had a problem on ip6 avahi resolve, and 1st post doesn't outline what's the problem and how you solve it, but more or less look like of how to setup an ad hoc network with ip6. By the way, since the release of Jessie, the configuration of network is supposed to be done via /etc/dhcpcd.conf than the old way of changing the /etc/network/interface.

Comment: @hcheung makes sense. We can flag this question and take it to the chat where the community can decide on it.

Comment: @hcheung Thanks for the contribution, but please take a look over the relevant [Meta thread](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/916/is-it-okay-to-ask-a-question-deliberately-and-answer-it-almost-instantly) in direct relation to this question. This approach is 100% fine here, and there's nothing inherently wrong with a long answer which may resemble a tutorial.

Comment: @goobering, thanks for let me know. Desai's tutorial is useful and clear in terms of setting up an ad-hoc network with ip6. It was his 2nd post that confused me.

Comment: Have you tried it. The post is almost a year old. Things might have changed.

Comment: About to try it (was away from my rbpi yesterday). Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Ok just tried. Works like a charm. That is, IPv6 configuration with Raspberry Pi3. 0 issues, connectivity confirmed with ping6. Now I just need to change the interface configuration to start ad-hoc mode automatically. Thanks!